# Splitting string into two columns, no delimiter (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have been given a list of IDs but as some of them are from the same sample, they have been put together in the same column (see below). I need to split them into the 2 IDs and want to add the second ID to a new column

```
                barcode
3               ABC00576ABC00576   
4               ABC00577ABC00577   
5               ABC00578   
6               ABC00579
```

So I would like a separation like this

```
3               ABC00576     ABC00576   
4               ABC00577     ABC00577   
5               ABC00578   
6               ABC00579
```

Also, some samples will have more than 2 barcodes so will need to be moved into 2 or more columns.

I am very new to Python and would appreciate some advice. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Are these values in a file like a csv file?  You can do this with regular expressions, which you can read up a little on here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: I haven't tried anything I am totally stuck - as I said, very very new to python! They are in a csv file which I have read in yes. Okay thank you for your help will have a look.

Comment: In that case, also do a little reading about how to get values out of csv files with python here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html